# Android rotation after startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities, `MainActivity` (contains `MainFragment`) and `SearchActivity`.

When the user clicks the search button in `MainActivity`, I open `SearchActivity` using `startActivityForResult()`. Then the user types in their query and I return that query as the result to `MainActivity` where I have a `searcher` object that actually performs a search with the query.

I'm running into an issue in the following circumstance, though: I am in `MainActivity` and click the search button. I go to `SearchActivity` where I proceed to rotate the phone. I type in my query and return to `MainActivity` where it crashes because `searcher` is null.

So I understand that when I rotate the screen `MainActivity` is getting destroyed and recreated, and I am saving the instance state, the problem I'm having is that `onActivityResult()` is getting called before `onActivityCreated()` in `MainFragment`. How can I ensure that `MainFragment` gets restored to its previous state before I handle the result?

EDIT:

Here is my (heavily edited; its for work) code.

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mainFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "fragment");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "fragment", mainFragment);
    }
}
```

Main Fragment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private Searcher searcher;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        searcher = new Searcher();

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // restore state
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
             if (data.hasExtra("query")) {                
                 String query = data.getStringExtra("query");
                 searcher.search(query);
             }
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
         super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
         // save state
     }
}
```

Comment: Post your code.  Most likely the problem is in `MainActivity.onCreate()`, but that is just a blind guess.

Comment: You could initialize `searcher` in `MainFragment.onCreate(...)`. I never had to use `onActivityCreated()` unless I was using loaders.

Comment: @EugenPechanec even when I do that, searcher is still null when I come back to `onActivityResult()`

Comment: what about `fragment.onAttach(Activity)`? Otherwise put in all lifecycle methods in your fragment a `Log` and in the `Fragment.onActivityResult()` as well to determine which method will be called in which order

Comment: Where are you initializing the searcher? Call it in onCreateView instead of onActivityCreated and then restore the saved state there itself.

Comment: Is Searcher part of the Fragment class or it own completely different thing?

Comment: it is its own class that is completely separate

Comment: Please revise your answer to my question about Seracher if it's not accurate.  The relationship of Searcher to the Fragment is very important.

Comment: It is accurate as far as I know, but I don't think its particularly important. What I am asking about is generally restoring the state when returning from `startActivityForResult`

Answer (score 0):

For example when I have troubles with WebView I have done this:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState ) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState); //Do your own action
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState); // Do your own action
}
```

And this may help with crashes:

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://goo.gl/6wE4Di"); //do your own action
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question, but I guess that could work.

Comment: Try to use this:

if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://goo.gl/6wE4Di"); //do your own action
    }
Use it every where you go from fragmet it should help. When you have tell me and I will try to solve it other way.
I hope it can help you.

Comment: Or you can try to to check if your return activity/fragmet is not null "if(fragment != null)".

You need to override the onSaveInstanceState method to persist the settings of your activity before fit rotates. Then, in the onCreate method, you can check to see if the Bundle argument is null. If not, then you are recreating your activity and should load the saved settings from it.

Comment: When your app is still crashing share your crash log here please.

Answer (score -4):

add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

in your MainActivity tag in Android Manifest.

Comment: Shoo! Go back to shadows!